# Function assigns incorrect float value in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I am trying to return a float value and assign it to a float variable, but the value of the new float is different from the returned one.

```
float getVoltageReading() {
    return 1.2f;
}


void updateUIReadings(uint8_t menuID) {
    float integerReading = getVoltageReading(); // digital voltage
}
```

In debugger I see that getVoltageReading return `1.2`, but the integerReading is assigned to be `1.06703091e+009`

Why is that?

Comment: Where are you seeing the incorrect value? Your code here never reads the variable. If there is more code involved in your actual program, you'll need to post at least the part that uses the `integerReading` variable.

Comment: Prototype not in scope and "implicit `int`" biting?

Comment: @DanielFischer: [Right on!](http://codepad.org/QBtPJMC2)

Comment: Yes, I have more code which takes the variable and copies into a char array. But that's irrelevant.

Comment: When I add a main that calls updateUIReadings() and include header files, integerReading gets a value very close to 1.2. (Not 1.2 since you can not represent all numbers with float). The value you supplied is way too off the scale, most probably something else is corrupting the stack.

Comment: @pmg how could I fix it?

Comment: @Arturs: get the prototype for `getVoltageReading()` in scope before calling the function ... possibly **by including the header where the function is declared at the top of your file that calls it**.

Comment: Consider carefully what Daniel's comment refers to (properly prototyping your function before it is called or actually defining it before it us used). As presented here, the code flow does not exhibit the nature of [the problem you're describing](http://ideone.com/V0gzru).

Comment: You can also verify that this is the problem by enabling full warnings and warnings-as-errors (e.g., `-Wall -Werror` in clang or gcc, but MSVC should have similar settings).  Working with full warnings and warnings-as-errors tends to help catch these kind of mistakes.

Comment: In support of @DanielFischer's comment - the printed value is the value of the bit pattern for 1.2f, interpreted as a 32 bit integer.

Comment: If the implicit int is the problem, then the solution is to get a modern C compiler! Such as `gcc -std=c99`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `getVoltageReading` function without an active prototype in scope, which means it is assuming that it will return an `int`. It *looks* like, from the way your question is organised, that it is in scope, but I can assure you it's not.

You can see that with the following two files, `testprog1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//float getVoltageReading(void);

int main(void) {
    float integerReading = getVoltageReading ();
    printf("%e\n", integerReading);
    return 0;
}
```

and `testprog2.c`:

```
float getVoltageReading(void) {
    return 1.2f;
}
```

When these are compiled and linked together, the output is:

```
1.067031e+09
```

because the float value being returned from `getVoltageReading()` is being interpreted as an `int`. If you uncomment the prototype in `testprog1.c`, it works fine because it interprets the float value as a `float`:

```
1.200000e+00
```

Comment: Or simply compile with a compiler that has been updated to the C standard during the past 14 years... The code in this answer will only compile on obsolete C compilers.

Comment: @Lundin, it compiles fine (albeit with a warning) on gcc in c99 mode. Although perhaps the warning bit is what you meant by your comment?

Comment: `gcc test.c testprog.c -std=c99` gives me `test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getVoltageReading' [-Wimp
licit-function-declaration]
test.c: At top level:
test.c:11:7: error: conflicting types for 'getVoltageReading'
test.c:6:28: note: previous implicit declaration of 'getVoltageReading' was here`

Comment: GCC version 4.6.2 on MinGW port.

Comment: I'm using 4.3.4 in CygWin and don't get the error. I _did_ get that error when they were in the same C file but separating them allowed compilation to go through. It may be that gcc has improved detection between 434 and 462 or that you have different default options but I believe that code is actually valid according to C99. The standard works on translation units and that's definitely two _separate_ units - the problem is instantiated at link stage.